# Mapping Linq-to-SQL classes to domain classes with nested collections

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've following mapping functions:

```
 private static Expression<Func<ActionComment, Domain.ActionComment>> MapActionComment =
      actionComment => new Domain.ActionComment
      {
        Id = actionComment.Id,
        Comment = actionComment.Comment,
      };

    private static Expression<Func<Action, Domain.Action>> MapAction =
      action => new Domain.Domain
      {
        Id = action.Id,
        Comments = action.ActionComments
                         .Select(ac => MapActionComment.Invoke(ac))
      };

    private static Expression<Func<Nc, Domain.Nc>> MapNc =
      nc => new Domain.Nc
              {
                Id = nc.Id,
                Actions = nc.Actions
                            .Select(a => MapAction.Invoke(a)),
              };
```

And the following Linq-to-SQL query:

```
_ctx.NCs
  .Where(n => n.Id == id)
  .Select(MapNc)
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

The resulting SQL statement is:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], -- columns  
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Actions] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[NCId] = [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[NCs] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Actions] AS [t1] ON [t1].[NCId] = [t0].[Id]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id]
```

The thing is that Comments collection of Action object does not load its contents (it's deffered till actual usage of collection).

Is there any way to force Linq-to-SQL to generate **ONE** single statement which would fetch Ncs, Actions and ActionComments?

Answer (score -1):

You should look at eager loading via Linq2Sql. For example, see this blog:
http://www.lowendahl.net/showShout.aspx?id=190

It seems, there are some problems, but it should work in gerenal.

Actually, if it is possible, I would suggest moving to EntityFramework. Right now LINQ2SQL is a legacy technology. In particular, EF have good support for eager loading by using simple `Include()` method like this:

```
_ctx.NCs
   .Where(n => n.Id == id)
   .Select(MapNc)
   .Include(nc => nc.Comments)   //EF to eager load relation
   .Include(nc => nc.Actions)   //EF to eager load relation
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: If you read linked article you wouldn't say "use eager loading" because eager loading in L2S is not so eager - only 1 level down. Thing is that I need 2 or more levels down. EF is not an option - it's somehow legacy system that I maintain.

Comment: I read the article, and I now, that there are limitations. I gave you at least the point where to look at.